# How to image MTDblock device?

Tags: mount

I am trying to image the mtdblock of an android 2.1 Sony Xperia phone that has YAFFS2 file system. I know there are mtdblocks and mtd files in the device. Using nanddump, I have successfully created images of mtd0, mtd1 and mtd2 partitions. But when I attempt to mount them, either with Linux mount command or busybox mount cmd, it says block device required. So apparently these images of mtd devices that I have in hand are of no use.

Now when I try to image the mtdblock device, it is giving me error

```
nanddump: MEMGETINFO: Inappropriate ioctl for device
```

I have enabled yaffs2 filesystem in my linux kernel but they also expect input image file of mtdblock device, that I am unable to make.

So the real question is, how to image MTDblock device?

Tried:

- change the r/w permission of mtdblock files to 777
- changed ro to rw of mounted partitions

No luck yet.